# System cannot find the file

Tags: java, file-io

I am using the Scanner libraries to build a file reader, I have followed the outline in the Libraries and it compiles fine, but when I run it I get a FileNotFoundException : text.txt (The system cannot find the file specified). The file is located in the same folder as the .java file but it still says that it's not there.

Below is the code that I have any help would be great.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Conjecture {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = null;

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt")));

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.next());
        }
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use the File class to get the absolute path of "text.txt" to figure out where Java is looking for that file.

Comment: Are you running from an IDE like Eclipse

Comment: Well if you are move the file to your workspace folder.It will surely work.

Comment: Consider to use the new NIO.2 File API and try-with-resources when working with files.

Comment: @chetanmehta thank you good sir!. I was using stdlib a number of weeks ago on a similar project and forgot that the file need to be in the workfolder and not the default package with the .java file.

Answer (score 1):

Your file needs to be in the working dir of your runtime JVM. If you are not sure about that, you can do the following :

```
File file = new File(".");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the file in the same directory as your .class, not your .java.  When compiling from an IDE the .class file usually gets placed in a build directory.  Using the absolute path would also work, as Kevin suggested, or adding the file as a resource to a jar file and loading it as resource.

Answer (score 0):

for debug purposes print `canonical path` of your file:

```
File file = new new File("text.txt");
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

so you can see where your file should be located